# Mdframe environnment on multiple page : top margin

Tags: margins, mdframed

I am using the package `mdframed` for examples in my report. The frames are split on several pages.

My problem is that on the second page the frame doesn't have any top margin. And this is very ugly.

Here is my code:

```
\usepackage{mdframed}

\definecolor{grisframe}{gray}{0.95}
\definecolor{gristitleframe}{gray}{0.85}
\mdfsetup{backgroundcolor=grisframe, skipabove=12pt, skipbelow=6pt, leftmargin=0pt, rightmargin=0pt, innertopmargin=12pt, innerbottommargin=6pt, innerleftmargin=12pt, innerrightmargin=12pt, frametitleaboveskip=12pt, frametitlebelowskip=6pt, frametitlerule=true, frametitlebackgroundcolor=gristitleframe}

\begin{mdframed}[frametitle={Exemple}]
Chaque parties relatives à l'analyse des processus -- à savoir les composants, la modélisation et les performances -- sont illustrées avec deux processus présentés ci-dessous. Blabla bla...
\end{mdframe}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `splittopskip=<length>`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\definecolor{grisframe}{gray}{0.95}
\definecolor{gristitleframe}{gray}{0.85}
\mdfsetup{backgroundcolor=grisframe,
 skipabove=12pt,
 skipbelow=6pt,
 leftmargin=0pt,
 rightmargin=0pt,
 innertopmargin=12pt,
 innerbottommargin=6pt,
 innerleftmargin=12pt,
 innerrightmargin=12pt,
 frametitleaboveskip=12pt,
 frametitlebelowskip=6pt,
 frametitlerule=true,
 frametitlebackgroundcolor=gristitleframe,
 splittopskip=2\topsep}


\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[frametitle={Exemple}]
\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: of course, splittopskip!